# Looping Linear Regression in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, predict

df_tmp

```
zipcode.  var1   var2.  orders
Z1.       20.     19.    20
Z1.       50.     28.    10
Z1.       80.     45.    26
Z2.       19.     36.    10
Z2.       20.     90.    16
Z2.       40.     59.    18
```

I am using the following function for overall prediction -

```
#split x and y
x = df_tmp.drop(columns=['orders'])
y = df_tmp['orders']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.20, random_state = 0)

from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import statsmodels.api as sm
from scipy import stats

X2 = sm.add_constant(X_train)
est = sm.OLS(y_train, X2).fit()
X_test = sm.add_constant(X_test) # add again the constant
y_test_predicted = est.predict(X_test)
y_test_predicted
```

However, I want to predict for every zipcode using a similar code. For-Looping might be extremely inefficient, looking for some suggestions on how this can be done

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a generator that contains the slices of the dataframe with different zipcodes, abstracting your modelling logic into a function and then mapping this onto this generator.

That will be much faster than using for loops.

Code here:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import statsmodels.api as sm

zipcodes = df_tmp['zipcode.'].unique()
different_df_sections = (df_tmp.loc[df_tmp['zipcode.'] == x] for x in zipcodes)

def calculate_predictions(df_tmp):

    x = df_tmp.drop(columns=['orders'])
    y = df_tmp['orders']
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.20, random_state = 0)
    X2 = sm.add_constant(X_train)
    est = sm.OLS(y_train, X2).fit()
    X_test = sm.add_constant(X_test) # add again the constant
    y_test_predicted = est.predict(X_test)

    return y_test_predicted

different_predictions = map(calculate_predictions, different_df_sections)
all_predictions = [x for x in different_predictions]
```

Comment: I get an error - 
ValueError: With n_samples=1, test_size=0.2 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters.

Comment: Did you add a train_size parameter when you called train test split? I also can't really say for sure without knowing more about the context for what you're doing, but you can maybe drop train test split if you're doing this on multiple subsections of the data then comparing results

Comment: Have edited now with another approach that I think is better...

Comment: Thanks for the help, the train test still does not seem to work for me. However - 
```
different_predictions = map(calculate_predictions, section_generator(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test))
```

changed to 

```
different_predictions = map(calculate_predictions, section_generator(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, zipcodes))
```

Still did not work.

However, if I dont use the train and test split, it works! I will try to deep dive a bit more to get the fix